# How can I implement a translation connector (or bot) in Microsoft Teams?

Tags: microsoft-teams, office365connectors

Is it generally possible to build a connector or a bot in MS Teams that translates a Teams message or thread at the push of a button? For example, from English to Italian or Spanish. Or vice versa. With [Google translate API](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/) for example? Or [Bing](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/translator/translatorapi.aspx)?

I find many examples of putting data into Teams. None, however, how to send data from Teams to other services (and process their responses).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Threads and messages themselves don't have an extension point and I can't think of clean way to implement a "do x to this thread/message" in the current UX.

That said, I can see where this would be a *very* useful extension point. Its an excellent idea and one I would highly recommend you add to the [Microsoft Teams UserVoice](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public-preview/category/182881-developer-platform). It would certainly get my vote.